# Replacing Strings with existed strings

Tags: c#

Ok so my goal is to change the first string after the iteration
first string: `defaultFile`
iteration string: `afterIteration`

I have tried using an extra string:

`string updatedFile = defaultFile.Replace(defaultFile + afterIteration);`

yet it still doesnt work, it says that the variable has already value

completed code is in this link

https://codeshare.io/5DXg9W

Comment: In codeshare you don't use 'replace'!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string updatedFile = defaultFile + afterIteration
```

Comment: main.cs(35,14): error CS0128: A local variable named `updatedFile' is already defined in this scope 

it's always that error

Comment: because you already defined that variable, if you denfined than remove the declare